# Will a mistake in my data collection for my thesis effect my whole grade?

Tags: research-process, research-undergraduate

I am currently doing my undergraduate thesis for psychology. I noticed in my data collection when asking the participants age i asked it wrong e.g. 18-21,21-25. Age is not one of my variables i am testing in this study and will have no implication on the results of my study. If i acknowledge this as a limitation and state how it wont impact results will this still have a big impact on my grade?

Comment: Only the instructor of your course can decide what will and won't impact your grade, though I can't see much reason for something like this to matter. I do think it's kind of a weak limitation to point out, though, in my opinion you'd be better off finding more interesting weaknesses that actually impact your results, I promise you that your study has some because every study does.

Comment: Consider not mentioning age at all in your thesis; information you collected but didn't use isn't really relevant and is not a limitation. Then you can include an appendix with the full text of the survey. In this case, I really can't imagine it would affect your grade at all even if they did notice the mistake in the appendix (though of course, only your professor's opinion counts).

Answer (score 1):

If age is not a variable used in the later analysis, then it cannot be wrong.

If you **should** have included age in the later analysis, then that may cost some points - depends on what they are looking for...

Including age in the original survey is usually a good thing as it means that that data may be suitable for different variations of studies ie the data is possibly more useful.